# Why the behavior of replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n") is so different from replaceAll("\\\\", "\\")?

Tags: string, scala

Why the behavior of replaceAll("\\n", "\n") is so different from replaceAll("\\", "\")?

I'm new to Scala. And I found that:

```
scala> """\n""" replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n")
res257: String =
"
"

scala> """\n""" replaceAll("\\\\", "\\")
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing
  at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendExpandedReplacement(Matcher.java:1020)
  at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:998)
  at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:1181)
  at java.base/java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2137)
  ... 28 elided
```

Why the behavior of the above are so different? My understanding is that the second call
  replaces double backslash with a single backslash, but why the second call crashes while the first once
  succeeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"character to be escaped is missing"** refers to **x** part of **\x**. The replacement string in the test case contains only **\** part. So this method expected **\\** to create **\** literal.

You can make the change over there and run it:

```
scala> """\n""" replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\")
res2: String = \n
```